# onClick event in HTML DOM sitting in javascript file calls javascript function which generates an error

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, onclick

The following code generates an error when the user clicks on any table value, whereas the called function should be revoked:

```
html += "<div>";
      html += "<table>"; // HTML table starts here
//Rows are generated using myData 2-D array already defined
    myData.forEach(function(value){
            html += "<tr>";
   //mykeys are keys for all the row values already defined
             for(mykeys in value){
             html += "<td>" 
//on Click event is attached with all the row entries or table values
     html+= "<a onClick=\"(e)=> \"compareMe(e,key,value[mykeys])\">" 
              html += "<span>" +value[mykeys] +"</span>" 
               html += "</a>" 
               html += "</td>"
            }
           html += "</tr>";
          });
              html += "</table>";
         html += "</div>";

        // This function is called on generating on Click event on the output values
 function compareMe(value){
          if(value==="2"){
          html += "<td>" +"X" +"</td>";
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += html;
            return html;
          }
       }
```

Comment: Please add what the error message is.

Comment: Kyle this is the error message generated everytime I click on any of the valuesthat are outputted in the rendered table:

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input